# Native dll kicked out of c# without error message

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, dll

Ocationally it appears to me that c# kicks out my native dll. How can I find out why or prevent this behaviour?

I have a (large) c# application (win32). For some time critical functions I wrote a native c++ dll. On user command a (start-)function is called in the dll which starts a thread. As a paramter the window handle of a winforms panel is passed in the call. The output of this thread is diaplayed in that window. While the thread is running the panel is not altered or changed in any way. The thread runs endless until the user calls the stop function in the dll which ends the thread. So far everything is working fine/as expected.

But every once in a while the dll seams to vanish. The output freezes without any user action. It appears, that the dll was removed from memory. When the user then calls the stop function, the dll seams to be reloaded, telling the user that the thread was not started before. No runtime error no message, nothing. I could not find a way to trace that bug. Is there a way to let c# tell why it kicked the dll out of memory? Or can I somehow nail the dll so it cannot be kicked out? Is there any tools around which could help me?

```
dll:
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_RunOutputThread = false;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    }
    return TRUE;
}

MYDRIVER_API long  Start(HWND houtputwindow){
    if(g_RunOutputThread) return -1; //thread already running
    g_RunOutputThread = true;
    g_OutputThread = thread(&OutputThreadFunction);
    return 0;
}

MYDRIVER_API long  Stop(){
    if(!g_RunOutputThread) return -1; //thread was not started
    g_RunOutputThread = false; // the only line (beside dllmain) that set this to false
    if (g_OutputThread.joinable()) g_OutputThread.join(); 
}



void DisplayThreadFunction(){
    try{
        while (g_RunOutputThread) {
        ... // the timecritacal work
        }
    }catch(...){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error in output loop!"...// does not appear!
    }
}


c#
[DllImport("MyDriver.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static int Start(IntPtr hWndOutput);

[DllImport("MyDriver.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static int Stop();


void OnStartButton_Click(){
    int ret = Start(pnOutput.Handle);
}

void OnStop_Click(){
    int ret = Stop();
}
```

Comment: not sure if this would solve the problem but you can try using the kernel32.dll methods of LoadLibrary(). Please, take a look at this [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258270/How-to-release-non-managed-library-loaded-into-man]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dorKKnight, I started implementing it when I finally found the cause for the strange behaviour, the dll was not removed from memory, it only seams so: The dll is called from a dialog that has a timer which calls the stop function after some time. When the dialog was 'aborted' the timer was not stopped (my bad) and when the dialog was opened again this timer was still running and called the stop function which leads to the unexpected end (freezing). And, of course, when the user calls the stop function then again the status was 'not started', the same as if the dll was loaded the first time.